# View "Recent Achievements" has no logs, but reputation goes down

Tags: discussion

Experienced not once. I'm just confused why my reputation goes down, but it couldn't be seen in *Recent Achievements*.

Just yesterday, my reputation was 2,572, but now it got down to 2,556.

Comment: it does show up there when you click on it and you see the list but you don't get a red box saying -6, that's really only evident if you gained more that you lost (ie. if you got +10 -6 it would actually have a green +4 box). unless of cause your saying that the -6 isn't even showing up in the list aswell

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42569409/concate-all-rows-specific-column-except-the-current-one-mysql/42569477#42569477 was deleted when the question it was posted to was. See the duplicate on how you can see this yourself.

Comment: Thanks,It means i couldn't seen in Recent Achievement?

Comment: That page,  doesn't have any up vote Score besides it down voted. any new rules / rules that i must know?